# Extract numeric data from matched regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have some temperature data in a csv file and I want to extract only the temperature for a say the first month of the year, and so after processing I want a list of `[1.4, -5.8]` in the example below.

```
1866-01-01 00:00:01;1866-02-01 00:00:00;1866-01;1.4;G
1866-02-01 00:00:01;1866-03-01 00:00:00;1866-02;-3.0;G
1900-01-01 00:00:01;1900-01-01 00:00:00;1900-01;-5.8;G
```

I thought of doing this with python module re, but I always have issues getting to grips with regular expressions! For instance my quick test below returns all lines when I only expect it to return the entries from the first month of the year...

```
import numpy as np
import re


regex = '\d{4}-01-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{4}-01-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{4}-01;[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+;G'

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as fid:
    for line in fid:
        match = re.findall(regex,line)
        if match:
            print line
            print match
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a CSV parser. Your regex cannot handle quoting anyway, and it's ugly.

Comment: I would have thought regex could handle these kinds of situations with ease? In any case how would you do it with a csv parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `csv` module, specifying `;` as the delimiter. The third column in the data is YYYY-MM, so check whether it's the first month and print the temperature if it is:

```
import csv

with open('data') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'):
        year, month = row[2].split('-')
        if int(month) == 1:
            print(row[3])
```

**Output**

```
1.4
-5.8
```

For comparison, here is the simplest regex that I could come up with to extract the required value:

```
import re

with open('data') as f:
    temperature = re.findall(r'\d{4}-01;(.+?);', f.read())
    print('\n'.join(temperature))
```

You can see how it takes more effort to read & understand the regex than it does the Python code.

There is an even easier way that relies on your data consisting of fixed width fields:

```
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[45:47] == '01':
            print(line[48:-3])
```

Comment: Thanks. Would regex not be recommended? I feel it could be useful getting comfortable with it as there are so many situations when you can use it to extract what you need when data is formatted a particular way. Obviously in this example your method works easily as well!

Comment: but this is getting -3.0, which the author of the question does not want.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for your effort! It works well, but do you have anything against the regex approach? I thought it would be the go to method for these kinds of problems or do you always try to use the csv module?

Comment: @Jack: it's not a complicated regex, but this code is going to be more readable and therefore maintainable than a regex. Even `str.split()` can be used for this very simple data format.

Comment: @Jack I would not recommend regex either since this you already have data that's formatted in csv and there exist parsers for that and they will be able to handle edge cases better. There will be plenty of opportunity for getting comfortable with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the folling regex:

```
^(?:\d{4}-01-.*?)(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

Demo and explanation of behavior: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN4hC6/2)
The number is in the first capturing group.
Alternatively, with a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=\d{4}-01).*?(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

Demo and explanation of behavior: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN4hC6/4)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put brackets around what you want to extract. So you should change the last part to `;([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+);G`.

Try this code and tell me if it works:

```
import re


regex1 = re.compile('\d{4}-01-\d{2}')
regex2 = re.compile('([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+);G')

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as fid:
    for line in fid:
        match1 = re.findall(regex1,line)
        if match1:
            match2 = re.findall(regex2, line)
            print line
            print match2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you response - but `match` is only printed as `5.8`

Comment: @Jack I fixed it now. I assumed that test.csv would always contain data in this format.